# Cant create a mysql database using Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to implement Spring Boot without embedded database like h2 and derby but instead with mysql. I keep getting unknown database error.

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties:

```
#Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'sampledb'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
```

If I use an embedded database like h2 then it is working without anything mentioned in the application.properties file but if I use MySQL I get this error. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure sampleDB is created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You connect to the database `sampleDB` which is not automatically created by mysql in contrast to h2.

You have to create it by yourself using `mysql -u <user> -p -e "create database sampleDB"`

Comment: I got the same error and I created the database using the mysql workbench beforehand. Would you happen to know why this error still occurs? Or does creating the database using mysql on terminal change something as opposed to workbench

Answer (score 43):

Neither the Spring Boot nor the Hibernate will not create database instead of you.

The setting below just creates tables and expects that DB already exists:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

However when you are using embedded DB (HSQLDB, H2 ...) the database will be created automatically. This is vendor specific behavior.

For MySQL you can use the following configuration to create DB automatically:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Pay attention to the connection parameter.

In this case database will be created automatically during connection.

Comment: Best answer on this page

Answer (score 6):

you need to add this to your configuration :

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDbName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Write your database name and spring will create the database automatically

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the database first.

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties change the line :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB
```

to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB?use=sampleDB
```

MfG.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

In your application.properties change the line :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB
```

to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampleDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Solution 2:

You need to create the database first.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.yml` file you should do like below.

```
jpa:
    hibernate:
    ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    properties:
    '[hibernate.format_sql]': true
```